# How Dart Determines whether a Certificate is a Self-Signed Certificate

Tags: dart

When I made App with Flutter Dart, I had a problem communicating with the server. HTTPS could allow self-signed certificates, but WSS did not find a solution, so I wanted to know how Dart decided that my certificate was self-signed certificate.